# Regex to add spacing between many strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to express this:

```
 print('{:<16s}{:>16s}{:>16s}{:>16s}{:>16s}{:>16s}'.format('Id', 'Loan Amount', 'Country Name', 'Status', 'Time to Raise', 'Total Number of Lenders'))
```

using a simpler way, for example:

```
print('{:>16s}*5'.format('Id', 'Loan Amount', 'Country Name', 'Status', 'Time to Raise', 'Total Number of Lenders'))
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the same string multiple times by doing `"xxx"*5` with the number outside

```
print(('{:>16s}' * 5).format('Id','Loan Amount','Country Name','Status','Time to Raise',
                             'Total Number of Lenders'))
```

---

Note that the exact correspondance of the first on give is the following as for `Id` the format is to pull to right

```
print(('{:<16s}' + '{:>16s}' * 5).format('Id', 'Loan Amount', 'Country Name', 'Status', 
                                         'Time to Raise','Total Number of Lenders'))
```